# Determining the maximum distance of two points in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of points (x/y each in one column) and need to determine the maximum distance of  any combination of pairs of points.

I'm only interested in the distance not the pair of points itself.

Right now I use a rough upper boundary estimation by calculating the length of the vector

```
(max(x)-min(x), max(y)-min(y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER:

```
=MAX((x-TRANSPOSE(x))^2+(y-TRANSPOSE(y))^2)^0.5
```

Also see: http://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/2010/11/27/maximum-distance-between-two-points/